# How to learn modelica?

Tags: modelica

I'm completely new to Modelica and was wondering what is the best way to learn on my own? Also I will be using it with MapleSim 5 (or 6 when it will be available) so any information regarding that would be helpful too.

I'll need Modelica to create a few components for a thermal model, then simulate with MapleSim and hopefully I will also manage to co-simulate with another software (EnergPlus) using FMI when it will be available for MapleSim and BCVTB.

Sorry for not being specific with my question, really any reference to a good Modelica guide would be great, thanks.

Comment: A first starting point is of course the [publications section on the Modelica homepage](https://modelica.org/publications). There you can also find two pdf tutorials for free.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, I am biased, but I like to think that my book ["Introduction to Physical Modeling with Modelica"](http://bit.ly/ModelicaBook) is a great way to explore the features of Modelica in the context of engineering problems.  I noticed that Wolfram [seems to recommend](http://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/resources/) the book as well.

But in the interest of balance, there are two books by Peter Fritzson on the topic of Modelica  as well.